# Problem deploying React website to Azure Storage using BitBucket pipelines

Tags: azure, yaml, bitbucket, azure-storage, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to build a react project and deploy to azure storage using BitBucket pipelines. I am getting an error when I add the last line:

```
- pipe: mspipes/azure-storage-deploy:2.0.0
     variables:
     SOURCE: 'upload'
     DESTINATION: $AZURE_DESTINATION
     DESTINATION_SAS_TOKEN: $AZURE_STORAGE_SAS_TOKEN
     DEBUG: 'true'
```

[image]

But nothing is actually highlighted!

**Full script:**

```
image: node: 10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    -step:
        name: Build React Project
        script:
          -npm install
          - npm run - script build
          - mkdir packaged
          - tar - czvf packaged / package -${ BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}.tar.gz - C build.
        artifacts:
          -packaged/**
    - step:
        name: Deploy to Azure Storage Account
        script:
          - mkdir upload
          - tar -xf packaged/package-${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}.tar.gz -C upload
          - pipe: mspipes/azure-storage-deploy:2.0.0
              variables:
              SOURCE: 'upload/'
              DESTINATION: $AZURE_DESTINATION
              DESTINATION_SAS_TOKEN: $AZURE_STORAGE_SAS_TOKEN
              DEBUG: 'true'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line with "variables:" was indented two spaces too many... should be lined up with the work pipe above it.